# How to store all the tables from pdf file to excel sheet using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tabular

1.I am able to get all the tables of PDF file.. but when I want to store all table, only the last table get saved in my excel sheet.

2.How to deal with these Overwritten values.

3.for loop last table will be saved in excel

```
import PyPDF2
import tabula
from tabula import read_pdf
import pandas as pd 
from xlwt import Workbook 



pdfFileObj = open('LAB.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
print(pdfReader.numPages)          #Total number of pages 
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(5)



#LAB is my pdf file
x = tabula.read_pdf("LAB.pdf", pages='all', multiple_tables=True)
for i in x:    #x values in list []
    print("printing all the table from the sheet", i)
    df = pd.DataFrame(i)
df.to_excel('tables.xlsx', header=True, index = True)
```

Comment: for every table you  want separate excel file ???

Comment: thanks, Single excel sheet is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can append pandas dataframe to a single dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in x:    #x values in list []
    print("printing all the table from the sheet", i)
    df_table = pd.DataFrame(i)
    df = df.append(df_table)

df.to_excel('tables.xlsx', header=True, index = True)
```

for storing it in separate excel you need to run df.to_excel() under  for loop

```
for i in range(len(x)):    #x values in list []
    print("printing all the table from the sheet", x[i])
    df = pd.DataFrame(x[i])
    df.to_excel('tables{}.xlsx'.format(i), header=True, index = True)
```